# Scrolling problem in Blackberry application

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, navigation, rim-4.5

I am not able to scroll through the application screen using trackball.
I am using Blackberry Pearl 8100 simulator.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it work on other simulators and just not the 8100? How about a real handset?

For your screen class you can try using the style attribute to specifically tell it to have vertical scrolling,

```
super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
```

similarly you should make sure that it's not set to

```
super(MainScreen.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL)
```

Comment: I also recommend looking into various field managers like VerticalFieldManager or HorizontalFieldManager which can result in elegant handling of layout once you're screen becomes more complex.